# Getting filename only from Scala/ Play

Tags: scala, playframework

With Scala/Play I am working with uploading files.

With my scala.html, I have

```
@helper.form(action = routes.HomeController.uploadFile,
    'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
    <input type = "file" name = "picture">
    <p>
        <input type="submit">
    </p>
}
```

to upload files and directs to the controller which has,

```
 import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils
import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.data.Form
import models.MemberService




 def uploadFile = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
      import java.io.File

      val filename = FileNameUtils.getName(picture.filename)
      picture.ref.moveTo(new File(s"/tmp/$filename"))
      Ok("upload completed")
    }.getOrElse {
      Redirect(routes.HomeController.index).flashing("error" -> "nofile exist")
    }
  }
```

and I am getting InvalidPathException error.

```
[InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 6: \tmp\C:\Users\jungj\Downloads\play-scala-starter-example.zip]
```

build.sbt

Here is my build.sbt

```
name := """play-scala"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.6",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.5.0",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34",
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test


)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

fork in run := true
```

I guess my val filename has the full name including the path and it causes this. 
I probably have to drop the directory and get name of the file only and put into val filename in order to moveTo correct path. I am pretty new to scala/play and want some detailed explanations. Can anyone help?

Comment: This path (`\tmp\C:\Users\jungj\Downloads\play-scala-starter-example.zip`) is totally messed up. In windows systems paths look like this - `C:\abc\def.txt`where as In Unix/Linux based systems paths look like this - `/abc/def.txt`. The path which you are providing is obviously an invalid path no matter which operating system you have.

Comment: Obviously it's path issue. Because new File(s"/tmp/$filename")  creates \tmp\C:\Users\jungj\Downloads\play-scala-starter-example.zip.
I guess filename includes the path and the name altogether( C:\Users\jungj\Downloads\play-scala-starter-example.zip.)
I assumed getting file name only (without path) can be a start.

Comment: Why don't you just try to split it by "\" and take the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename which you get by `picture.filename` describes the actual path of the uploaded file on the user's computer.

In this case it looks like the user was using a windows machine, and the actual path of file was `C:\Users\jungj\Downloads\play-scala-starter-example.zip`.

So, the value of `/tmp/$filename` will be `/tmp/C:\Users\jungj\Downloads\play-scala-starter-example.zip` which will be a totally invalid path.

So, what you actually need is a way to reliably extract actual filename from the foreign path in user's computer.

You can use `org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils` for this,

Add `commons.io` as dependency (in your build.sbt),

```
libraryDependencies += "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.6"
```

Now you can extract filename as follows,

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils

val filename = FilenameUtils.getName(picture.filename)
```

Comment: Failing to import FilenameUtils here. Can you provide me a little more help?

Comment: causing compilation error,  not found: value FileNameUtils

Comment: It is `FilenameUtils` not `FileNameUtils`. That was a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After correcting a typo, I was able to get appropriate path, but still has an issue: 
`[NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\jungj\AppData\Local\Temp\playtemp3096865473101773127\multipartBody2012383688196248099asTemporaryFile -> \tmp\sample-applications-master.zip]`


I think 
`picture.ref.moveTo(new File(s"/tmp/$filename"))` 
is to duplicate the file from "path with name" (will be helpful if i can find what this method is actually for) but simply switching name to a not-yet-built location doesn't help me to upload and copy the file.